# Linux: How to feed a multiple line bash shell command output, to a g++ statement?

Tags: bash, shell, command, g++, line

I'm under linux/mac, and using libxml2 to parse files. In order to make it convenient that my code could compile/link on any posix platform, I found this:

```
$xml2-config --libs --cflags
-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/lib -lxml2 -lz -lpthread -licucore -lm
-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/libxml2
```

Well it's good, but as long as this command outputs multiple lines, it seems only 1 first line is received if I integrate it with g++ command line like below:

```
g++ `xml2-config --libs --cflags` mytest.cpp
```

It only reads in the "-L" line, and ignores the "-I" line, so compilation error.

How to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Typically, that's the "right" way (although it assumes that none of your paths contain whitespace or anything that can be mistaken for a pattern to expand). I would expect it to work, but you might try two separate commands `g++ $(xml2-config --libs) $(xml2-config --cflags) mytest.cpp`.

Comment: Are you *sure* the compilation error is caused by a missing `-I` argument?

Comment: You could simply replace the newlines with spaces : `g++ $(xml2-config --libs --cflags | sed 's/\n/ /') mytest.cpp`. Untested but you get the idea

Comment: The commandline is quite all right. What compilation error? What code?

Comment: Alternative to `sed` ... `tr '\n' ' '`